# How is the configuration of a cross-platform project in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I need to develop a multiplatform application (Android, IOS, WEB and maybe Desktop) with backend in django rest framework using google cloud plataform. 
What flow is recommended?
Which of the products and solutions offered should I use? Is it possible to implement a web site in GCP or should I deploy it to a normal site host and connect it to the backend? 
Sorry for the levels of questions. I am a beginner in the cloud and I am really lost in the way these technologies are used.

Comment: GCP is a great platform for hosting applications.  I'd suggest having a read at https://cloud.google.com/solutions/websites/ and then hitting the books.  Think of GCP as resources for running your apps.  This includes compute, networking, disk and a world of services.

Comment: João, start by figuring out the easiest thing you can deploy, once you're past that point, it gets easier (or just more specific)